# How to generate a random value from an input?

Tags: java, math, random

I am looking for a way to generate a random value from a given input based of a seed.
I'll give a code example for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class Seed {

  public double generateRandom(double input) {
    // What goes in here?
  }

}
```

This is how an example program could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Seed seed1 = new Seed(), seed2 = new Seed();

  System.out.println("Result of seed 1 with 69: " + seed1.generateRandom(69));
  System.out.println("Result of seed 2 with 69: " + seed2.generateRandom(69));
  System.out.println("Result of seed 1 with 420: " + seed1.generateRandom(420));
  System.out.println("Result of seed 2 with 420: " + seed2.generateRandom(420));

  System.out.println("Result of seed 1 with 69 is still: " + seed1.generateRandom(69));
  System.out.println("Result of seed 2 with 69 is still: " + seed2.generateRandom(69));
}
```

The output being:

```
Result of seed 1 with 69: 0.5
Result of seed 2 with 69: 0.65
Result of seed 1 with 420: 0.2
Result of seed 2 with 420: 0.34
Result of seed 1 with 69 is still: 0.5
Result of seed 2 with 69 is still: 0.65
```

What would the Seed class look like?

Comment: What's the reason you want a class like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, an example implementation might look something like:

```
public class Seed {

  private long seed = new Random().nextLong();

  public double generateRandom(long input) {
      return new Random(seed + input).nextDouble();
  }
}
```

Pay attention that parameter of generateRandom in this implementation is `long`.

Comment: This will fail for a call like `seed1.generateRandom(69.0)`. In order to maintain the signature `generateRandom(double input)` as mentioned by OP, you need to cast `input` to `long`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Oh, the input type is arbitrary. It doesn't matter what type it is the way I plan on using the method.

Comment: @Ajay Have you even read or ran the code before you modified others accepted answer.  This will not give different answer for 2 different references with same input.

Comment: @Ajay, please don't modify my answer without a note. Your modification broke the required behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Can We use something like this :

```
class Demo {

    public double generateRandom(double input) {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(input);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param input start of the random random number generated
     * @param bound upper bound of the random number generated
     * @return
     */
    public double generateRandom(double input, double bound) {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( new Demo().generateRandom(10));
        System.out.println( new Demo().generateRandom(10,15));
    }

}
```

Reference 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextDouble(double,%20double)

Comment: Always returns different values for me.

Comment: I think we want to generate random number for every execution. Do we want to generate same values for a similar input ?

Comment: Yes, basically. I've got a solution that works now though, but thanks anyways!

Comment: I agree that ThreadLocalRandom is the preferred way to generate random numbers, but the requirement in the question *cannot* be satisfied with ThreadLocalRandom, because it does not allow to set seed. The implementation which satisfies the requirements needs the possibility to set the seed. So, please, don't modify other peoples answers.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash ,  @ Alex I have just asked why we are doing that for my understanding. No intentions to change the answer. :( I'm sorry if this caused any inconvenience.

Comment: It's just an unusual requirement: each instance of Seed class should return the same random number if provided with the same input. **But**, different instances of Seed class should return different results. Read the expected output carefully. Result for seed1(69) and seed2(69) are different. Your solution always gives the same answer for the same input.